# Train.py cannot detect the column names with special characters in it

Tags: python, scikit-learn, training-data

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V82O7.png)

I have added an image above showing that my dataframe could not detect the column name ['curb-weight'] as it has the (-) special character when I do training and testing. Below is my code and the error message.

```
> plt.scatter(train.curb-weght, train.price,  color='blue')
> plt.plot(traincurb_x, regr1.coef_[0][0]*traincurb_x +
> regr1.intercept_[0], '-r') #-r is for the colour of the line, can be
> change to -g, you will see green plt.xlabel("curb-weight")
> plt.ylabel("price")



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-fbf2ee41bbd6> in <module>()
----> 1 plt.scatter(train.curb-weght, train.price,  color='blue')
      2 plt.plot(traincurb_x, regr1.coef_[0][0]*traincurb_x + regr1.intercept_[0], '-r') #-r is for the colour of the line, can be change to -g, you will see green
      3 plt.xlabel("curb-weight")
      4 plt.ylabel("price")

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5485         ):
   5486             return self[name]
-> 5487         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5488 
   5489     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'curb'
```

I have also added a dataset reference FYI. Please help me thanks!

[Dataset refence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61Xyc.png)

Comment: There's a typo in your code, you called _curb-weght_ instead of _curb-weight_.

Comment: You can reference columns as `df['column name']` instead of `df.column name` (this wouldn't be a valid name)